# Append text and add class with fadeIn

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I have a form with `AJAX`. I want to make it `fade in` when the `submit` make success or failed. If is success The `script` add the `class has-success` to the `div` and change the content with `append`. I want to make it `fade in` when change the content and class. I tried with `fadeIn(500)` after the `append` but didn't work. You can see a live example [here](http://residenciarucab.es/rucab/contacto.html).

```
<div class="container">
<form class="ajaxForm" action="https://formcarry.com/s/YN2IlAj4rfL" method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8" >
<div class="form-group">
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="Correo" placeholder="Correo electrónico"><!-- use this to reply visitors and prevent spam via akismet -->
</div>
<div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="Nombre" placeholder="Nombre"></div>
<div class="form-group"><textarea rows="4" class="form-control" id="textarea" name="Mensaje" placeholder="Cuéntanos"></textarea></div>
<input type="hidden" name="_gotcha"><!-- use this to prevent spam -->
<div class="form-group"><input type="submit" class="btn-contacto float-right"><div class="spinner-border" role="status">
  <span class="sr-only">Cargando...</span>
</div></div></div></form></div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $(".ajaxForm").submit(function(e){
        $('.spinner-border').css("display", "block");
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr("action");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: href,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(response){
                if(response.status == "success"){
        $(".ajaxForm").html(response).addClass("has-success");
        $(".ajaxForm").append( "<p>¡Gracias! Contactaremos contigo lo antes posible.</p>" ).fadeIn(500);

                }else{
                    alert("An error occured.");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey check this solution first you need to send response back from your server.

```
if (isset($_POST['Correo'])) {
// your server side logic or send success or failed response
echo json_encode(['status' => 'success']);die;
}


 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
<div class="container">
<form class="ajaxForm" action="https://formcarry.com/s/YN2IlAj4rfL" method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8" >
 <div class="form-group">
 <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="Correo" placeholder="Correo electrónico"><!-- use this to reply visitors and prevent spam via akismet -->
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="Nombre" placeholder="Nombre"></div>
  <div class="form-group"><textarea rows="4" class="form-control" id="textarea" name="Mensaje" placeholder="Cuéntanos"></textarea></div>
  <input type="hidden" name="_gotcha"><!-- use this to prevent spam -->
  <div class="form-group"><input type="submit" class="btn-contacto float-right"><div class="spinner-border" role="status">
  <span class="sr-only">Cargando...</span>
  </div></div></div></form></div>`
```

Javascript code i append message after form

```
$(function(){
$(".ajaxForm").submit(function(e){
        $('.spinner-border').css("display", "block");
$(document).find('#msg').remove();e.preventDefault();
var href = $(this).attr("action");
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: href,
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(response){
    $('.spinner-border').css("display", "hide");
    $(".ajaxForm").addClass("has-success");
    $(".ajaxForm").after( "<p id='msg'>¡Gracias! Contactaremos contigo lo antes posible.</p>" ).fadeIn(500);
}else{
      $('.spinner-border').css("display", "hide");  
                alert("An error occured.");
            }
        }
    });
});
});
```

Hope this will solve your problem. let me know worked for you or not

Comment: My page is an static html, so the $_post call don't work for me.

Comment: $post logic all you need to  `<form class="ajaxForm" action="https://formcarry.com/s/YN2IlAj4rfL" method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8" >` in this page where you submit your form you need to send resonse usig `json_ecode()` hope you understand

Comment: so where I insert this? if (isset($_POST['Correo'])) {
// your server side logic or send success or failed response
echo json_encode(['status' => 'success']);die;
}
before the <form> tag?

Comment: @PedroCorcheroMurga no where you want to submit your form its example for server side. when submit form check post url in network section and then add logic on target url which is this https://formcarry.com/s/YN2IlAj4rfL where you submit your form

Comment: @PedroCorcheroMurga or simple you can insert my js code and submit form and   add this to ajax `success: function(response){console.log(response);}` check your response and add logic according your response